# What is the meaning of the color of the node sockets in the node editor?

Tags: interface, node-editor

I have been searching on the web and I can't find this. What is the meaning of the color of the node sockets in the node editor?

Comment: Related: [Cycles - (Shader) Nodes - inputs outputs - What are the exact data types?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102520/cycles-shader-nodes-inputs-outputs-what-are-the-exact-data-types)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

- **Grey** is a single value
- **Yellow** is a tuple containing 3 values; the red, green, and blue channels of a color.
- **Purple** is a tuple containing 3 values. Used for vector/coordinate information.
- **Green** is a shader closure, representing a description of how light will interact with a surface or volume. This one can only be connected into other green sockets.

Note that these will be converted to/from each other automatically as much as possible:

- Yellow and purple can be connected to each other without any loss of information (under the hood they are pretty much the same).
- Grey can be connected to yellow or purple without any loss of information (all three values in the tuple will the same value)
- Yellow and purple can be connected to gray, but [will be converted to a single grayscale value](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/32242/599):

[image]

More info on this link:

**[Cycles - (Shader) Nodes - inputs outputs - What are the exact data types?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102520/cycles-shader-nodes-inputs-outputs-what-are-the-exact-data-types)**

Comment: I would say that it's blue, not purple, but maybe that's just my color scheme (#6363c7)..  And I would summarize the blue nodes as "vector/coordinate" information since they are used for UV and normal information.

Comment: @MutantBob Mine are the same color, but for whatever reason they look purple to me. Added note about vector/coordinate information

Comment: I found this by searching "node editor gray purple".