# Material doesnt show up in rendered view

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor

The material of certain objects in the scene doesnt show up. Also the scene is tainted dark, is this related to the sky texture as background? How do I correct this?

Material view: Mountain and beach texture is there.
[image: Material View]

Rendered view: Mountain and beach texture is not there. River tho.
[image: Rendered View]

Node Setup for the material of both mountain and beach.
[image: Node Setup]

World background set as sky texture.
[image: World Sky Texture]

Comment: I think it's not a good idea to use Mix shaders in this case, 'cause you are trying to plug Color output to Shader input. It may not work properly. In your case it's way more logical to use *Color* > *MixRGB* node instead.

Comment: @Mr Zak I'll try it.

Comment: @Mr Zak Nice! This works! Thank you a lot, maybe you could write it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When combining several outputs into some other inputs, you should remember what socket you use and how.

In your case, you don't see any textures in Rendered view because information from Color outputs couldn't be converted properly being plugged into Shader inputs. 
And the blue color fullfilling everything in your case is the color of the environment texture (which is added by the *Sky Texture* node).

Instead you should mix colors, textures, etc using nodes designed for that, i.e. *Color* > *MixRGB* one. Its ouput is also of Color type, so you can continue adding some color information to the node tree.

In the very end, when you know you're done with color, plug the final Color output into the Color input of the *Diffuse* (or another one) shader. After that, you may combine *shaders* (add some *Glossy* or *Transparent* or adding new colors / textures with new *Diffuse* shaders or  whatever) with *Mix Shader* node, but there won't be any conversion between Color and Shader type.

[image]

You may want to look at [meaning of the color of the nodes sockets](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33915/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-color-of-the-node-sockets-in-the-node-editor) for more info on different sockets' types.

Comment: Much appreciated!

Comment: @Jonathan glad I could help!