# How can I bypass a node?

Tags: interface, node-editor

Sometimes when working with nodes it is useful to see what my setup looks like without a certain node.  I know I can delete a node without breaking the chain with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and then undo with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, but that is kind of cumbersome.

Is there a way to easily bypass a node like this, connecting the inputs to outputs like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> does, only without deleting it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**This is called *Muting* a node.**  You can mute or unmute a node by selecting it and pressing <kbd>M</kbd>.  Muting a node will connect the inputs directly to the outputs according to [datatype](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/33919/5705) in the same way as *Delete With Reconnect* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>).

[image]

When muted the header of a node will turn red and it will display red wires showing which inputs are connected to which outputs.

Comment: This may not work only in one case - *Math* node. If it's connected and even muted, it won't add any operations, *but* still will continue converting color data.

Comment: @MrZak I don't experience that.  To test it I plugged a colored texture into a math node and the math node into a color socket.  When unmuted the output is B/W (obviously), but when I mute the math node the output *is* colored.

Comment: Seems like it was fixed in latest versions. In 2.75 you [would face that](http://imgur.com/dGUtrns) which I remember because someday I've lost several hours to understand why the texture isn't colored.