# What are the node plugs called?

Tags: node-editor, terminology

To help me communicate better what is the correct name for node attachment points?
[image: nodes with the part in question highlighted]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [Sockets](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/node_editor/nodes/parts.html#sockets)

In the Blender manual's page about [Node parts](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/node_editor/nodes/parts.html) it is said that **Sockets** is the name for the ...

> ...input and output values from the node.
>
> They appear as little colored circles on either side of the node. [...].
>
> Each socket is color-coded depending on what type of data it handles.

Comment: If you are interested in color-data relationship, see related question [What is the meaning of the color of the node sockets in the node editor?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33915/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-color-of-the-node-sockets-in-the-node-editor)