# Why is my material solid white?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I was following the tutorial of Blender Guru on YouTube, to make an Earth in Blender. I was finished with the first part. But then somehow my clouds were deleted (the Material of Clouds doesn't exist anymore). And I started making a new material for the clouds. But the whole sphere is white, cloudds can't be seen like in the first time. What could be the reason?

[image]

The big sphere is the earth and it is fully white. If I turn the opacity of the Clouds down (eye symbol), the Earth can be seen. So the problem is with the clouds

Comment: I can see a mistake in your node setup, the "Fac" input of your Mix shader can't be driven by the "Generated" output of the texture coordinate node...

Comment: Also the **Mix** shader shouldn't be plugged in *Color* input socket; either it represents actual material's surface being connected to **Material Output** node or it should be substituted with another node. Probably you should swap **Diffuse** and **Mix** shaders.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Like Mr Zak said I had to swap diffuse and Mix -solved-

Answer (score 1):

The texture coordinates cannot control the shader mix factor.

An image is not a shader so it shouldn't be connected to a shader mix.

The mix shader shouldn't feed a color to the diffuse shader...

What you need is the Texture coordinates to control how the image texture is mapped. (Ideally you should unwrap the object for proper texture placement and use UV coordinates... but you can use Generated while you learn to unwrap)

The dark and bright areas of the image control how the transparent and diffuse shaders mix.

The color for the diffuse shader determines the color of the clouds.

[image]

I suggest you watch the so-called "tutorial" over a few times to familiarize with the steps taken... Nodes do require a certain order as the results will be different depending on how they are connected.

Comment: further reading: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33915/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-color-of-the-node-sockets-in-the-node-editor and https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/nodes/input.html?highlight=texture%20node  and https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/nodes/shaders.html?highlight=shader%20nodes