# How to make a real mirror on blender with cycle engine

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, mirror

I need to add a mirror object in Blender. I'm looking for the existing objects, but can not find any object. I am wondering how I can add such an object.

[image: mirror picture]

Comment: Are you using internal or cycles?

Comment: I am using a cycle and I have found the solution.

Comment: @startingBlender good that you found a solution. Please write your own answer so that someone with the same question in the future might learn from your experience.

Answer (score 3):

I felt this was a good question, so I've added an answer for future users. Also, maybe some of my info will add to what you've already discovered.

To make a mirror in cycles, use a glass shader (for obvious reasons), a fresnel shader (to ensure that the light hitting the mirror is complimented by the angle at which it’s shining, as described [here](http://www.blenderguru.com/articles/making-better-materials/)), and a glossy shader at low roughness (which is similar to a glass shader but will bend light in a slightly different way, adding to the realism). These can all be easily found by hitting <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> and typing the node name. The base object is a simple mesh plane.

[image: Nodes for mirror]

I’ve added two glass shaders with 2 different colours, for additional realism.

[image: mirrored eyes]

Be sure to add another coloured plane behind the mirror, so the light rays stop at the mirror glass (and are then reflected) instead of passing right through.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully uderstood your proposal: why shaders are the input of a shaders's color socket? And why fresnel-minxing with an empty shaders?

Comment: @360ueck I believe the proposed material is not correct: the green socket shouldn't be connected to the yellow color socket. See: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33915/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-color-of-the-node-sockets-in-the-node-editor

Comment: Oh my gosh, thanks for pointing it out. I'll fix it

Comment: A real mirror will be a piece of glass with a reflective material coating on the back. If you are going for realism, don't just use a plane, but have the object have some thickness, use a glass material on it, then on face at the back of the object invert the normals and use a glossy shader. In a real mirror you'd be getting a [double reflection](https://s3.amazonaws.com/ksr/assets/001/189/199/7ec4146cecd8dc0501b98cd991c54636_large.gif?1381855467)

Comment: @cegaton The socket mistake didn't make a difference, which is probably why I didn't notice it. I rendered it out and it still looks the same. I threw this together really quickly (one might say I was going for convenient realism). I appreciate your tips though since I'm still fairly new to shaders. Do you mind if I incorporate your comment into my answer? I know there was some discussion on meta about "stealing" comments.

Comment: @360ueck edit your answer with all the information you feel would make it better