# How to reflect a beam of light on a mirror using cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, blender-internal-render-engine, light

In the context of a tutorial, I need to create this experience using a light spot on cycle engine.
We can replace persons with other objects.  I tried to do it using this answer [mirror](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52125/how-to-make-a-real-mirror-on-blender-with-cycle-engine?noredirect=1#comment89100_52125) but the mirror does not reflect the light. here is my .blend [exemple](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/41805). Any help?

[image: A mirror reflects a beam of light]

Comment: That's an effect you won't be able to do currently with cycles. Try rendering in a different rendering engine like luxrender.

Comment: @cegaton can we do it with blender render (internal render) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8645/1853

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VyLOZWevi8g

Comment: @cegaton, thanks for your suggestion. It work with luxrender.