# RGB to Material Output?

Tags: materials, node-editor

[image: hi]

I want to connect *Combine RGB* with *Material* output.

How can I convert the yellow dot to green dot?

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33915/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-color-of-the-node-sockets-in-the-node-editor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have a shader between them, like this.

[image]

The different shaders are found under *Add -> Shader*, and they are explained in the manual. [Shader Nodes](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/nodes/types/shaders/index.html)
Commonly used ones are Diffuse, Glossy and Glass, and the Mix Shader is highly useful to combine the effects of several shaders into one material.