# Material Turns Black When Adding a Colour Node

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I've got a bit of a problem with one of my materials. In the node editor, when I put the image texture straight to the surface output of the mesh it shows up perfectly in the rendered viewport. Same thing when I put it through a diffuse node first.
When I add any colour node in the chain it makes the mesh turn completely black. Any reason why this is? It happens with any colour node (Gamma, Hue/Sat, Bright etc.)

There's some photos below of what happens before and after adding a colour node to the chain.

Thanks in advance :)

Before:
[image: Before]

After:
[image: After]

Comment: Add the gamma node before the shader (before Diffuse) not between it and the output. If you look at the slot color (green, yellow) that indicates that they are not compatible. More globally, shaders are 'terminal' nodes.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have been stuck with this problem for ages and it was just down to me not looking properly. Thanks!

Comment: read:http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33915/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-color-of-the-node-sockets-in-the-node-editor