# Why does adding shaders take the colour out of grass in render mode

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, node-editor, shaders

I am making a field of grass using particle systems. The set up has 2 different clumps, green and green/brown plus some weeds and flowers. In materials mode, when I add shaders, (translucent and glossy for example,) I get the great effect that I want. When I go to render however the colour in the grass is completely gone. (I'm only setting the glossy shader to .002 by the way.) Anyway, glossy or not glossy, translucent or not, if I even go near changing a basic image texture>diffuse>output node setting all the colour goes in render mode. I have had some issues recently with seeing multiple shader and texture nodes in materials mode apparently because I'm on a MAC but this seems to be the inverse problem. Any Ideas?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful to be able to see your results as well as you material nodes. Please se the Edit option to edit you question and add screenshots and/or any other information.

Comment: So the middle picture is materials mode and the bottom is in render mode. If i don't use any shaders then the render result is fine.

Comment: Thank you so much......if I put the diffuse before the 2 mix shaders all is wonderful......its the kind of thing that I can look at for hours and still not see!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be careful what information you connect on the node sockets.

Sockets have colors (Yellow, Green, Gray or Purple) for a good reason: so that you use the correct kind of information.

You can't connect color information (yellow) to the green input of mix shaders.

Likewise, plugging the output of a mix shader to the color input of an other shader makes no sense. The output of a shader can only be plugged in to mix shaders or to the material output sockets.

[image]

Please read the following link for a detailed explanation:

**[What is the meaning of the color of the node sockets in the node editor?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33915/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-color-of-the-node-sockets-in-the-node-editor)**

---

Read also: [Cycles and nodes, trying to use Diffuse BSDF as color source for Glossy/Subsurf Scattering BSDFs.. not working](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/83081/1853)