# Crash report. Cycles shader graph connect: can only connect closure to closure

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

My Blender model keeps crashing and I don't really know why when I render it get to between 80% and 95% on updating BVH and just flat out crashes. I am using cycles with 2.78c

Crash report-Cycles shader graph connect: can only connect closure to closure (Bump.Normal to Add Shader.Closure2).
Cycles shader graph connect: can only connect closure to closure (Bump.Normal to Add Shader.Closure2).
Malloc returns null: len=16 in Cycles Alloc, total 2348295728
Malloc returns null: len=8 in Cycles Alloc, total 2348295664
Malloc returns null: len=8 in Cycles Alloc, total 2348295672
Error: Unrecognized Exception
Error: Unrecognized Exception

Anyone Got Any idea this is all I got from the command prompt thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the crash is reporting an issue with shaders then investigate into how the materials are created. Are you connecting a bump map to an add shader node? Nodes have colors that determine what kind of information should be plugged: purple should connect to purple, yellow with yellow and grey with grey... A green input is expecting a green output.

Read: [What is the meaning of the color of the node sockets in the node editor?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33915/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-color-of-the-node-sockets-in-the-node-editor)

[image]