# Object doesnt render with diffuse

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, shaders

today I was working on the look of a bowl in my project. 
It is UV unwrapped and I created a material for it.

Now I want to top border to be in a different color. When I now mix the 2 colors together that I want my mesh to have and put it into my diffuse color it will turn out white in the render. Which is confusing me since I do not even use white for the bowl.

[image][image]

and when I just put the Diffuse to black everything is fine.

Comment: Do not mix shaders (in this case Diffuse) with MixRGB node, use Mix shader instead. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33915/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-color-of-the-node-sockets-in-the-node-editor. Mix colors either with 2 Diffuse shaders and one Mix shader or with 2 MixRGB nodes + 1 MixRGB node for mixing and 1 Dffiuse shader

Comment: To clarify/expand on what Mr Zak said: that PBR dielectric group node is expecting RGB data in its Diffuse Color input socket. You've sent it BSDF shader data instead. And if it were me I would download the release candidate for 2.79 and use the Principled BSDF for PBR - much easier.

Comment: Oh yeah. I didnt notice that I used a Mix rgb.

Comment: But I am somewhat confused now. The Mix shader also just has a green output. When I put that into the diffuse channel it renders it black but still without the red part. 
But I now know how I can change that. Instead of using 2 Diffuse Shader I just have to use 2 RGB inputs with the Mix rgb node. 

Thank you guys.

Comment: read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33915/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-color-of-the-node-sockets-in-the-node-editor

Comment: Can you use [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) to post the .blend?

Comment: Of course. 
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3761" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3761/)

Comment: Your problem is that you mix two shaders (diffuse nodes) using a RGBmix node and then send this to a color input. The diffuse color input of the PBR node is should be a color (yellow dot) not a shader (green dot). 
You should not use diffuse node to define the black and red colors, but use a RGB color instead.