# Material not rendering properly

Tags: materials, shaders

I'm quite new to Blender (I'm using 2.79), and I've been using the Principled BSDF (with Cycles). What I want is to use a mask (the image is temporary) to paint a motif on the side of the cup.
In the image below, I have 2 3D View, one with Rendered, the other with Material. Material is what I want, but why isn't it the same for the Rendered?
The Rendered one seems to be using the old version of the material, that I used before modifying the nodes to add the mask, which is also displayed in the Material preview on the right side.
The cup only has one Material, assigned to all its faces.
What is going on? How do I fix it?
[image: screenshot]

Comment: See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95830/principled-bsdf-image-texture-isnt-appearing/95834#95834 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33915/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-color-of-the-node-sockets-in-the-node-editor/33919#33919

Comment: So I should not be using Mix Shader there, but what can I use instead to get the result I want?

Comment: Shader output (green output socket) should go into shader input (green input socket). In simple words either connect Mix shader to Material Output or Principled to Material Output with that texture you used as roughness (you may need to adjust / invert it depending on workflow)

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I fixed it. Thanks Ray Mairlot for sending me related posts.

Instead of a Mix Shaders with Diffuse BSDF, I am now using a MixRGB, and it works perfectly.

[image: screenshot solution]