# Textures show up in 3D View but not in Cycles Render

Tags: materials, node-editor

Here you can see two very different viewports, but they are the same **scene**. The bottom right is the un-rendered view on Material View. On the first picture you see the rendered view, but it does not show the texture applied to the cubes and to the lines... why?

[image: 3D & Render View]
.

.
[image: Render View]

[image: Nodes for the textured material]

These are the **node** elements for the textured material.

[image]

Comment: Your node tree is an incorrect mess. You have shaders outputting into color cockets, color ramps driving color ramps, shaders mixing with colors. Cleanup your setup. Not sure what you are trying to achieve here, but make sure you match your socket colors.

Comment: Read: [What is the meaning of the color of the node sockets in the node editor?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33915/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-color-of-the-node-sockets-in-the-node-editor)

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos How would you go about fixing them? What would you change exactly?

Comment: For starters: move your Diffuse Node so that it's between your last Color Ramp node and the Mix Shader node.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is not your node-setup but the use of the textured viewport mode. this mode is not very reliable for previewing as it only displays the last selected texture of our node setup and doesn't take texture coordinates and transforms into account. if you want a texture preview without using the rendered view, switch to material view instead.

**Your node setup**

[image: screenshot]

1. Delete unused nodes
2. Don't use color ramps as an input for color ramps (take the node socket's color into account!): The color ramp's input only takes the value of a pixel but no actual color information and translates them to the color gradient. basically your first color ramp is almost useless.
3. The mix shader expects two shaders as an input (green socket), don't mix a color and a shader with it
4. same here, connect the mix shader directly into the material output and put the diffuse shader between the color ramp and the mix shader