# Rendering a scene with shaderless objects results in a completely black image

Tags: rendering, particles

I want to do a 2d animation of a particle system.

I created a background, put my camera up, set the mode to orthographic.

I created an object for my particles to use, set them shaderless, created a particle system and chose that object to be rendered.

[image: camera, material and particle properties]

<sup>(camera, material and particle properties)</sup>

When I view the animation through the camera it looks nice but when I render the animation, it takes a lot of time and the image comes back just black.

[image: viewport vs render]

<sup>(viewport vs render)</sup>

I tried putting up a light, but that didn't work.

[blender project file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cykr3rhjxup07ui/particles1.blend?dl=0)

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and [add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene and settings. Don't rely on others downloading your project just to understand your question. Please read: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this

Comment: Switch to blender render then use the same node setup and it should work.

Comment: I can't switch to blender render because I need the particle info node for the particles to fade in and out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It's not going to work because of child particles

Unfortunately, since you are rendering **child particles**, you can't achieve your goal at the moment (Blender 2.79).

This is because the [*Particle Info* node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/input/particle_info.html)

> ... *currently only supports parent particles. Info from child particles is not available*.

I don't know the roadmap for this.

### Other details

First, you are currently seeing a good "material" view, because it doesn't rely on Cycles. But if you change to the **"rendered" view** (you don't have to make an actual render, but it's practically the same), it falls back to black.

[image]

Now, even if you **disable the "children"** in your particle system, it's not going to get any better

[image]

this is because your material is, indeed, "shaderless"!

If you add a shader (like the **"*Emission Shader*"**), though:

[image]

*Voilà!*

Unfortunately, though, it won't work if you enable child particles again.

Comment: @Benni never plug yellow sockets to green inputs, they are very different kinds of information. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33915/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-color-of-the-node-sockets-in-the-node-editor