# Having trouble adjusting depth of procedural texture with several mixes

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor, procedural

I've been working on a procedural texture for the lunar surface, including craters, surface rocks, and the undulations in the ground. At this point it's for features on a scale of about 1 to 30 meters.

I had something I was satisfied with but added another layer of noise to make the undulations more irregular on slopes. The section of crater it's planned to go on is large and it looked too simple for such a large area. When I did that, the small craters and rocks stopped being visible. I've been trying to adjust it, but now it's barely perceptible when rendered. It looks near to right in Material view, though.

[image]

The material has gotten a lot more complicated than ones I've made before, and I'm concerned I'm going about it the wrong way. How can I adjust this so that the rendered texture looks about the way it does in Material view (but rather stronger)?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The mix node to the right is a "mix shader" node. You are mixing colors, not shaders, so swap it with a color mix node. Does that change something?

Comment: @yann - oh, yeah it mostly fixes it. I didn't realize that has to be consistent all the way through. I made almost the same mistake just a week ago, and read about sockets, but then when i see examples, it seems common for people to mix socket colors. Remembering not to mix colors with shaders is easier for me.

Comment: here is a great explanation about the conversion between the different node sockets: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/33919/36012