# Baking a material with a diffuse color and an image texture

Tags: materials, export, baking

I want to bake an object material for importing it in a game engine.
[image]

a cuboid with a half cut arrow in one face.
I created the material in Cycles Render like this
[image]

But whenever I bake it I always get some fail result like[image]

This is my .blend file.
[image]

Can somebody help me make a perfectly baked image for this material?
Thanks to the community in advance.

Comment: The information you posted is not sufficient to help you with your issue. If possible, please upload a .blend file, see https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/658/including-a-blend-file

Comment: Instead of plugging shader (Diffuse BSDF) into mixing color (Color > MixRGB) use either simple color input (Input > RGB) or another MixRGB node. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33915/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-color-of-the-node-sockets-in-the-node-editor