# Blender 2.79. Rendered image show only color and not UV mapped texture

Tags: rendering

I have problem in blender 2.79.

When I want to render a model but with image texture render model appears black although uv maping is correct. But when I apply defuse shader it shows its color.
Please help me regarding the problem.

Thank you.

[image: With defuse shader]

This picture shows with image texture
[image: with image texture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cycles you need shaders, they determine how the light rays bounce on (or go trhough) the surfaces of an object.

You can't apply textures directly on the material output. (if you notice there are different colors on the sockets. Green can only be connected to green, yellow goes with yellow, purple with purple, and so on). The material output should be connected to shader information only.

In your case you need to connect the color of the image texture to the color input of the diffuse shader, so that the image gets mapped on the faces of the object.

[image]

Read: [What is the meaning of the color of the node sockets in the node editor?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33915/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-color-of-the-node-sockets-in-the-node-editor)

Comment: Thank you it's working