# how to get generic texture to show in cycles render

Tags: cycles-render-engine

How do you make the built in textures like voroni, musgrave, etc. render in cycles.

Comment: Hi ron, Welcome to Blender.SE. ***What is your question?*** Can you please post a short, clear concise sentence with a question mark, which sumarizes your goal.

Comment: if you don't want to use image texture you don't have to unwrap, just go in the Node (Shader) Editor, create a Texture node (like voronoi), plug it in the factor of a MixRGB, choose 2 colors in this Mix, plug it into a Diffuse node, plug the DIffuse into an Output node

Comment: *"add a texture but in the render there is no texture, only generic colored image"* this likely means there's no UV map for the object while UV map is set to be used. In Cycles Image texture is added the same as any other procedural texture like Voronoi, Noise etc - from Shift+A > Texture in the Node editor

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't plug a texture directly to the material output node.

In cycles you need to have a shader node.

Textures need to be plugged in to the color input of the shader.

Remember that cycles is trying to emulate the way light and surfaces work in the real world. Shaders determine what happens to light rays when they reach a surface, they can be reflected, diffused or go through the surface for example.

Textures should to be plugged in to the color input of the shader, so that the rays reaching the surface of the object respond to the light using such texture.

(if you notice there are different colors on the sockets. Green can only be connected to green, yellow goes with yellow, purple with purple, and so on). The material output should be connected to shader information only.

The most basic node tree should look like this:

Texture---Shader---Material Output

[image]

But there are many more ways to use textures.

To use the texture to mix colors, use the fac output of the texture and plug it to a color mix node.

[image]

You can also use the texture as a factor to mix two different shaders:

[image]

You can mix multiple textures, colors and materials or use textures to mix other textures.

[image]

**The next concept you need to learn is that textures get mapped using coordinates**, but that will have to be the subject of a different question if you are interested. Suffice to say that procedural texures (not images) can be used with no UV mapping. Having said that, however, UV coordinates will allow you to do very precise placement of textures.

Do yourself a favor and watch Bartek Skorupa’s video on how to [Manipulate texture coordinates](https://youtu.be/kAUmLcXhUj0?t=264)

Read also: [What is the meaning of the color of the node sockets in the node editor?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33915/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-color-of-the-node-sockets-in-the-node-editor)