# How to make a material with texture in Blender 2.8?

Tags: texturing, materials

I'm trying to apply a blue texture to a material, but the texture is not displaying in the 3D view port.

[image: setup]

I'm using blender-2.80-387c1f2e0d5d-linux-glibc224-x86_64

What should I do? What I'm missing? Bellow is the .blend file.

[File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d4oyYQlKOTQWLcHbm94otBDMl3qd95oM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: You would need to connect the texture to the color socket of the shader to have any effect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get generic texture to show in cycles render?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/144317/how-to-get-generic-texture-to-show-in-cycles-render/144326#144326)

Comment: Thank you Cegaton!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the node setup to achieve the result:

[image]

And here is the .blend file:

[LINK](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iwB70RKmHg6e0EgQU0xLbZLwUpIBqV-t/view?usp=sharing)