# What's the purpose of Node Wrangler's Viewer Node?

Tags: node-editor, add-on

With Node Wrangler enabled, I can quickly preview a texture node with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd>.

But what puzzles me is that it creates a Viewer Node, which seems unnecessary:

[image]

[image]

As shown above, the result doesn't look different if I connect my Texture Node to Material Output directly.

So why does Node Wrangler create this Viewer Node? In which situation would it be necessary?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a technical detail but using the *Emission Shader* as *some kind of bridge* is **technically correct**.

---

The color of each socket represents a specific data type. Quoting from [What is the meaning of the color of the node sockets in the node editor?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/33919/31447):

> - **Grey** is a single value
> - **Yellow** is a tuple containing 3 values; the red, green, and blue channels of a color.
> - **Purple** is a tuple containing 3 values. Used for vector/coordinate information.
> - **Green** is a shader closure, representing a description of how light will interact with a surface or volume. This one can only be connected into other green sockets.

As you can see the *Surface* socket from the *Output* node is **green** so it **expects an incoming shader** (closure) and no other kind of data. However, that you're allowed to plug any other node type into the *Surface Socket* is actually a great feature...

[image]

*For the sake of completeness:* In case a float socket (grey) is connected to rgb (yellow) the resulting `g` and `b` channels are just a copy of `r` to fill it up.

Comment: In older versions of Blender, there was no implicit type conversion when plugging non-green sockets into Surface. It did nothing. That is the context Node Wrangler was originally made in. The emission viewer node was mandatory until fairly recently.