# Why my object is not illuminated

Tags: light

so I have my basic scene and one object (girl) is not illuminated by light source I did not touched anything it has just a texture as material.
Edit:
Render engine is cycles the object is imported fbx

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, please [add more information](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/197488/edit) about your scene. What are the material settings? What is the render engine? Was the object created in blender or imported from another software? You may [add your file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) (please [pack all textures](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/blend/packed_data.html#pack-all) also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are plugging a [texture node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/image.html#image-texture-node) directly into the [output node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/output/material.html#material-node).

You must plug the texture node into a shader node such as a [Principled BSDF](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/principled.html#principled-bsdf) first in order to get the color information from the image to the output correctly.

Below would be the correct setup:

[image]

See [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33915/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-color-of-the-node-sockets-in-the-node-editor) for more information on closures.

Side note, you also do not have a camera in the file you provided. Add one and you will be all set :)

[image]