# How to change a certain parameter of all principled shaders in my blend file?

Tags: materials, node-editor, shaders, workflow

I have like 100 objects, each with its own material, different mesh, own texture and UV maps. I want to immediately adjust only one parameter for all the materials, say: metallic but I want to keep separate textures, so I won't just link materials.
I found that "copy to selected" does not work for material properties (this would be a cool feature, by the way).
I also watched a tutorial about group nodes and yeah, it's cool to control many materials with a single node, but I would sooner move 100 sliders manually, rather than set up a node tree for each material.

If there's no tool for it, I would be happy with a simple python script that takes all materials in the model and changes them one parameter.

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121129/discussion-on-question-by-michalpe-changing-one-parameter-of-multiple-materials).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would have to iterate through all materials, get their node trees and find the *principled bsdf* to set its default values. Demo on how to change the `Metallic` value for all materials in the file:

```
import bpy

for mat in bpy.data.materials:
    if hasattr(mat.node_tree, "nodes"):
        for node in mat.node_tree.nodes:
            if node.type == 'BSDF_PRINCIPLED':
                for input in node.inputs:
                    if input.name == 'Metallic':
                        input.default_value = 0.7
```

If you'd like to change another property of the principled shader, here is a complete list:

`Alpha`, `Anisotropic`, `Anisotropic Rotation`, `Base Color`, `Clearcoat` `Clearcoat`, `Normal`, `Clearcoat Roughness`, `Emission`, `Emission Strength`, `IOR`, `Metallic`, `Normal`, `Roughness`, `Sheen Sheen` `Tint` `Specular`, `Specular Tint`, `Subsurface`, `Subsurface Color`, `Subsurface Radius`, `Tangent`, `Transmission`, `Transmission`, `Roughness`.

Note that some of them are actually vectors (yellow and purple socket) so you'd have to assign a *tuple* instead. Demo on how to set the `Base Color`:

```
import bpy

for mat in bpy.data.materials:
    if hasattr(mat.node_tree, "nodes"):
        for node in mat.node_tree.nodes:
            if node.type == 'BSDF_PRINCIPLED':
                for input in node.inputs:
                    if input.name == 'Base Color':
                        input.default_value = (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
```

Further reading: [What is the meaning of the color of the node sockets in the node editor?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33915/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-color-of-the-node-sockets-in-the-node-editor)