# How do I iterate over all selected objects and change a property on their materials?

Tags: python

```
import bpy 

for material_slot in bpy.data.objects['Cube'].material_slots:
    material_slot.material.show_transparent_back = False
```

I have managed to access to the data of one object by name in Blender 2.93, but I cannot find a way to do it for all selected objects instead of by name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Iterate through all [objects in selection](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.context.html?highlight=selected_objects#bpy.context.selected_objects), iterate through [all material slots using a nested loop](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=slots#bpy.types.Object.material_slots) to get the material reference and finally set the [property](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Material.html?highlight=show_transparent_back#bpy.types.Material.show_transparent_back):

```
import bpy

C = bpy.context

# Iterate through all objects in selection
for ob in C.selected_objects:
    if ob.type not in ('LIGHTS', 'CAMERA', 'VOLUME'): # OPTIONAL
        # Iterate through all material slots
        for slot in ob.material_slots:
            if slot.material is not None:
                # Set the property
                slot.material.show_transparent_back = False
                slot.material.diffuse_color = (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
                slot.material.use_backface_culling = True
                # ... whatever
```

In case some materials are assigned to several objects, you can also [create a set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) out of unique materials and assign the value per item of the set instead of iterating through the same slots over and over again which will improve performance ([thanks to @batFINGER](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/227968/how-do-i-iterate-over-all-selected-objects-and-change-a-property-on-their-materi/227969#comment384732_227969)).

```
import bpy

C = bpy.context

# Create the set
mats = set(slot.material for o in C.selected_objects for slot in o.material_slots)

# Iterate through all unique materials
for mat in mats:
    # Set the property
    mat.show_transparent_back = False
    mat.diffuse_color = (0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    mat.use_backface_culling = True
    # ... whatever
```

**Related**

- [How to change a certain parameter of all principled shaders in my blend file?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/215420/how-to-change-a-certain-parameter-of-all-principled-shaders-in-my-blend-file)
- [How to assign a new material to an object in the scene from Python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23433/how-to-assign-a-new-material-to-an-object-in-the-scene-from-python)
- [Control Cycles material nodes and material properties in Python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23436/control-cycles-material-nodes-and-material-properties-in-python)

Comment: Couldn't find link, going to be a pest and suggest `set(filter(slot.material for o in context.selected_objects for slot in o.material_slots))` will return a set of all materials used by selected objects, 1000 objects could all use same material, in which case it there is no need to set same prop 1000 times. All objects have a `material_slots` collection.

Comment: All ideas to improve it are welcome, thanks @batFINGER

Comment: For the one liner lovers : `[setattr(m, "show_transparent_back", False) for m in (set(filter(lambda m: m is not None, (slot.material for o in bpy.context.selected_objects for slot in o.material_slots))))]`

Comment: Cool, got much love to spread in this case @Gorgious