# No color output for Musgrave texture

Tags: node-editor

I was following a Ducky 3D tutorial and at this timestamp [4:19](https://youtu.be/PAbJNDXU54s?t=259)

I need a Musgrave texture with a color output, but mine only has a "height" output.

I looked up on the Internet and several Blender users have had this problem, and they usually solved it by using a ColorRamp.

But how? I tried it and my smoke didn't become white, only its shape changed a bit. Where do I need to input/output my ColorRamp to make my smoke white like in the tutorial?

**SCREENSHOTS**

Without ColorRamp, plugging the height into the fac doesn't work. The smoke is still black.

[image: smoke simulation with black output]

With a ColorRamp but I'm not sure how to use it and where to plug it, I just changed the color of the ColorRamp to white but the smoke is still black :/

[image: The same but with a color ramp.]

Comment: When you copy a URL from YouTube, you need to check the "Start At" button to get the timestamp.

Comment: Ugh.  That's a 2.8 Tutorial. The problem is that Musgrave, Voronoi, and the volume shader all changed.  I think you'd be better off finding a 2.9 tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

I've had a look at the tutorial and added remarks at the end of this answer because they are more related to the tutorial than to the *Musgrave Texture* node.

**How to Colorize the Musgrave Texture**

The *Musgrave Texture* node has a grey node output *Height* that outputs a single float number. The yellow color nodes work with an RGB tuple. And a purple vector node has 3 values, an XYZ tuple. Blender converts them automatically. Read here more about it: [What is the meaning of the color of the node sockets in the node editor?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33915/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-color-of-the-node-sockets-in-the-node-editor)

That been said, if you want to map the single float number to an RGB color tuple, you can use a *Color Ramp* node that represents the entire color spectrum.

To do this, set the *Color Ramp* node to `HSL` and `Far`, and select the same color for the start and end. For example, make both red (hex `FF0000`) and you will get all colors. The *Musgrave texture* output is colorized when you connect the nodes. The RGB color value then can be used for the XYZ vector input of the *Voronoi* texture for more modifications/randomness.

[image: example screenshot]

### Addendum

**Remarks About the Tutorial**

The tutorial uses an early experimental alpha version of Blender 2.8. I've downloaded Blender 2.80.74 (release candidate 1 of 3) which has the same Musgrave node but the output is still more blocky:

[image: result in blender 2.80]

**Node Changes and Adjustments for Blender 2.82+**

To create this volumetric smoke animation in new Blender versions you need some adjustments:

- increase the strength of the *Area* light. Default is nowadays 10 W. That's not enough. It controls the brightness and the color. Try something between 300 W and 1000 W. The example is `1000 W`.
- the *Voronoi* node has been changed. You need to square the *Distance* output with a *Math* node.
- the *Musgrave Texture* node has been changed. See above.
- to get a smoother render to decrease the *Volumetrics > End* value to `4 m` in the *Eevee Render Settings*.
- the start/end color of the *Color Ramp* node for the *Musgrave Texture* node controls the amount of "Spaghetti" that you get, more black/dark or bright/white on the image that is. To be able to change the color conveniently use a *Hue Saturation* node and change the *Hue* value. This shifts the color palette. To do this easily by sliding the value with high precision there are the *Math* and *Value* nodes.

- decrease the *Detail* value of the *Musgrave Texture* node to make the fog/smoke smoother.

**Final Setup**

[image: node setup blender 2.92]

Make sure you are using Eevee and in *Render* view using scene light and scene world (black). Keyframe the X rotation of the *Mapping* node from 0° to 360° over 361 frames for a looped animation. That's the Ducky 3D tutorial.