# Image texture showing up in texture mode but not render

Tags: rendering, materials

I'm fairly new to texturing in blender and I was trying to make an american flag and set up a whole scene for it, but when I went into render mode the flag appeared black. I've gone into the nodes and made sure that I have an image texture connected to the output and the correct image chosen. I've uv wrapped the flag texture to make sure it shows up correctly and I have a texture with the flag set up but when I go to render mode I only see black [image: screenshots]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have connected the image texture directly to the surface output, but it needs to be connected to the *Color* input of a shader, for example a diffuse, like this.

[image]
<sub>World map courtesy of NASA, downloadable in several pixel resolutions from [NASA Visible Earth](https://visibleearth.nasa.gov/view.php?id=57730)</sub>

Below is the same material as it appears in the node editor, to make it clearer how to connect them.

[image]

In case your texture has an alpha channel, that doesn't get passed through the *Color* sockets. Instead it's passed separately through the *Alpha* socket. This can be used to mix multiple shaders, depending on the alpha channel, but to simply use it for transparency, connect it like this.

[image]

The logic here is, that when the alpha is 1.0 (i.e. fully opaque), the lower *Shader* socket to the *Mix* shader is passed to the material, and when the alpha is 0.0 (i.e. fully transparent), the upper *Shader* socket gets passed to the material, and anything in between, causes a corrsesponding mix of the two to get passed to the material.

Comment: @C.Pendergrass Glad I could help. You may also find these two posts on how to connect node sockets to each other useful: [What is the meaning of the color of the node sockets in the node editor?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33915/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-color-of-the-node-sockets-in-the-node-editor) and [How are color images used as input values in nodes?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32236/how-are-color-images-used-as-input-values-in-nodes).