# Geometry Nodes - Color Value as Float

Tags: geometry-nodes, vertex-paint

First, I'd like to provide some context.  I have a low resolution 3d map.  I made this map by subdividing a hexagon and applying a Displace modifier to it.  A little color-ramp magic in the shader, and I have something that's conceivably usable for my purposes:

[image: An island render]

However, switching between the displacement texture and the rendering shader is inconvenient for painting changes onto the model.  Before, it was the only way to do things, but now, I thought I'd try to use the Geometry Nodes system to displace my vertices with Vertex Paint as the input instead of a texture.

The problem is, the Displace node uses the texture's *HSV value* at each vertex directly, which is different from the color values visible in the spreadsheet editor.  For instance, while a color with an HSV value of 0.0 has an internal value of 0.0, and a color with an HSV value of 1.0 has an internal value of 1.0, a color with an HSV value of 0.5 is stored with a value of 0.216 per the spreadsheet editor.

How do I convert the stored value into something approximating the HSV value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How are color images used as input values in nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32236/how-are-color-images-used-as-input-values-in-nodes)

Comment: @Gorgious No, that question is 100% unrelated.  Firstly, I'm not using images here.  Second, the problem is that the value I'm expecting - the color luminance - is not the value reflected in the spreadsheet view.  This difference is reflected in the vertex color itself, not post-conversion, so the conversion described in the linked question cannot be the problem.  Furthermore, a lot of the nodes for working with colors simply don't exist in Geometry Nodes view, so I couldn't solve my problem the same way I might if I were working with Shader nodes.

Comment: Could you maybe add a little more information then ? Post a screenshot of you spreadsheet editor and the expected behaviour, etc.

Comment: I'm voting to leave this question open since OP can't use the linked answer.

Comment: Also might be helpful: [What happens when a vector is fed into a value slot of the add node?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/267155/60486)

Answer (score 1):

In **Blender 3.3+** you can solve this as follows:

[image]

In this version the node `Separate Color` offers you the possibility to choose between *RGB*, *HSV* or *HSL*.

The value for the vertex color is stored in the attribute *Col*, which you can query with the node `Named Attribute`.