# What happens when a vector is fed into a value slot of the add node?

Tags: node-editor, mathematics, vector

I was wondering what happens when a vector is fed into a *Math -> Add* node. Notice that I'm asking about the *Math -> Add* node, not the *Vector Math -> Add* node.

My guess was that the node automatically works with the vector module, but I noticed that with different normal vectors the output is different.

Can somebody explain the behavior of the node in this case?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Vector values convert to ⚫ scalar values by averaging all three components, therefore the following material should be white:

[image]

(both branches compare as equal)

⚠ At very big values the $ε = 0$ starts to fail due to floating point inaccuracies:

[image] (383 m cube)

Crantisz'es answer is incorrect, if it worked by converting  vector through  color to ⚫ scalar, then this material wouldn't be black (I even increased εpsilon to `0.1`):

[image]

[image]

Vector is Converted to color (and vice-versa) by simply treating XYZ as RGB (I think it's fair to say it's reinterpretation, not conversion, the values in memory don't change), however,  **vector and  color convert differently to ⚫ scalars**:

- vector to ⚫ scalar: $v = {1\over3} x + {1\over3} y + {1\over3} z = {x+y+z\over3}$
- color to ⚫ scalar: $v = 0.2126r + 0.7152g + 0.0722b = $ `luminance(rgb)`

[image]

[image]

For completeness, ⚫ scalar converts both to  vector and  color by triplicating (repeating) its value on all 3 components, which maintains luminance, and so is a reverse operation for both $➡⚫$ and ➡⚫.

### Geometry Nodes

In gnoodles the same rules apply, but additionally:

- ⚫ Float (Scalar) values convert to  Boolean as *True* if they are positive ($> 0$)
- Vectors convert to  boolean as *False* if all the components are zero, otherwise to *True*. You can reason about it as the length of vector being used in the logic of scalar to Boolean conversion (the length is never negative but can be $0$).
- Color is first converted to ⚫ Float (using its luminance), and then converted to  Boolean.
- ⚫ Float converts to  integers by *truncating*, which is discarding the fractional part (rounding towards zero; flooring positive values and ceiling negative values).

Comment: Thank you. I tried it out with many different vectors and, indeed, the Compare returns always true.

Answer (score -2):

Vector converts to color, and the color data is converted to its gray scale equivalent

From [Blender Wiki](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.2/interface/controls/nodes/parts.html?highlight=data%20conversion#conversion):

> Some socket types can be converted to other socket types either
> implicitly or explicitly. Implicit conversion can happen automatically
> without the need of a conversion node.
>
> For example, color and float sockets can both be placed into one
> another. Once a socket conversion is made data may be lost and cannot
> be retrieved later down the node tree. Implicit socket conversion can
> sometimes change the data units as well. When plugging a Value input
> node into an angle socket will default to use radians regardless of
> the scene Units. This happens because the Value node has no unit while
> the angle input does.
>
> Valid conversions:
>
> Between color and vector – in this case the using individual color
> channels to store the vector.
>
> Between color and float – the color data is converted to its gray
> scale equivalent.
>
> Color/float/vector to Shader – implicitly converts to color and gives
> the result of using an Emission node.
>
> Explicit conversion requires the use of a conversion node for example
> the Shader To RGB node or the RGB to BW Node node. The Math Node node
> also contains some functions to convert between degrees and radians.

Comment: This answer doesn't mention vector to scalar conversion, unless I understood correctly that you claim when converting  to ⚫, since it's not listed in *"valid conversions"*, the actual conversion becomes  ➡  ➡ ⚫ (which is incorrect as I argue in my answer)