# why does a noise texture multiplied by 1 turn black and white?

Tags: node-editor, color, mathematics, shader-nodes

I am trying to follow a [Tutorial](https://youtu.be/ARoa4eyv1jc) about distortion. I don't understand why a math node (multiply) turns a noise texture, which gives me RGB values, into black and white ones. From my understanding, every RGB value is a vector, for instance (3,2,5). If I multiply it by 1, shouldn't it stay all the same? Can someone explain what's going on in the backend?

[image: noise]

[image: B/W noise]

Comment: "*Every RGB value is a vector, for instance (3,2,5). If I multiply it by 1, shouldn't it stay all the same?*" No, to stay the same you should multiply the vector by a vector as well, otherwise it is converted to a float.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I see so the vector is a float now and a float equals black and white values? Is this correct? Thank you!

Comment: Yes that is correct. Check the *Vector Math* nodes instead to keep color information

Comment: As @DuarteFarrajotaRamos says, to multiply a vector you cannot use a simple _Math_ node, you need a _Vector Math_ node. With that you have two main options for multiplying the color: either _Multiply_, where you can enter different values for R, G and B channels, or if you want them to change uniformly there's no need for entering three values, uniform multiplying is achieved by using the _Scale_ option, where a single float is multiplied to all three channels.

Comment: Related: [What happens when a vector is fed into a value slot of the add node?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/267155/60486)