# How does blender converts a color into a factor

Tags: shader-nodes

Say I have a constant RGB color value and plug it into the input factor of the color ramp.
[image]

Does anyone know how does blender casts a RGB color to a one dimensional value? Does it first compute the amplitude of the color vector and then passes that as the factor, or does it apply color ramp per component of the input vector?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens when a vector is fed into a value slot of the add node?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/267155/what-happens-when-a-vector-is-fed-into-a-value-slot-of-the-add-node) ($v=0.2126r+0.7152g+0.0722b$)

Comment: Yes. That was what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: @Luke I think it's fair to call this a duplicate.. it's fixed without needing a separate answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It uses the "luminance" of the color, from a HSL model, which is a generally-agreed upon representation of the *perceptual* brightness of color.  The luminance weighs the green channel more highly than the blue channel.  You can, of course, do any math you want on your color to cast it to a factor in whatever way you'd like.

[image]