# Can someone offer a detailed explanation on data types and their conversions?

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes

I don't fully understand how data types are converted when their sockets are connected. Can someone help me fill in the blanks or better yet, give us a proper diagram about how this happens?

### [**Data Type Definitions**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/attributes_reference.html)

**Boolean.** True or false value.
*Boolean In-depth: A value of either 1 or 0 with 1 = True and 0 = False.*
**Integer.** 32-bit integer.
*Integer In-depth: -*
**Float.** Floating-point value.
*Float In-depth: -*
**Vector.** 3D vector with floating-point values.
*Vector In-depth: -*

[image]

### **Data Type Conversions**

**Integer $\rightarrow$ Boolean.** Given integer n, if n $\leq$ 0, then return 0 = False. Otherwise, return 1 = True when n $\geq$ 1.
**Float $\rightarrow$ Boolean.** Given float n, if n $\leq$ 0, then return 0 = False. Otherwise, return 1 = True when n $\geq$ 0.
**Vector $\rightarrow$ Boolean.** If vector is (0,0,0), then boolean returns 0 = False. For every other vector, return 1 = True. *(Why can't I get a 0 = False value with a vector other than (0,0,0)?)*
**Float $\rightarrow$ Integer.** Truncate.
**Vector → Float.** Mean. Average of scalars within vector represented as a float.
**Vector $\rightarrow$ Integer.** Mean and Truncate. Average of scalars within vector represented as float. Then truncated as an integer. *(Not too sure if the scalars within the vector are truncated before calculating the average or after.)*
**Boolean $\rightarrow$ Vector.** If boolean 0 = False, then return vector (0,0,0). If boolean 1 = True, then return vector (1,1,1).
**Integer $\rightarrow$ Vector.** Given integer n, then return vector (n,n,n).
**Float $\rightarrow$ Vector.** Given float n, then return vector (n,n,n).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens when a vector is fed into a value slot of the add node?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/267155/what-happens-when-a-vector-is-fed-into-a-value-slot-of-the-add-node) Maybe I could rework the answer… Also I disagree with the *"Actual"* value for boolean, it is stored as a single bit in memory (not always, sometimes it's stored as many more bits, with many bits wasted, just so values are aligned), and translates to $0$ or $1$ numerically. Also the bit is often interpreted as $0$ or $1$, but using the same logic a float is actually an int.

Comment: Vector is simply 3 floats. 2D vector is 2 floats. Color is... Depends on version, 3 or 4 floats (sometimes includes alpha). Except byte color is 3×8 bits integers in range $[0, 255]$. Oh and there's also quaternions (rotations), I don't know how they convert, I think they just don't (invalid connection).

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Oh!? I did not notice that you already had an answer to this question. Yes, I couldn't quite understand the manual's simplified definitions of the terms so, I included them in my question. I, for one, do feel that the computing lingo tending to go over my head. So, I appreciate the complete and detailed explanations that folks can provide.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady I didn't even notice that the color attribute was represented numerically so, I didn't include it. lol! As for Quaternions, I can say that you are correct about them, and they normally give invalid connections when connecting to other data types. I typically use the new nodes, like euler to rotation or rotation to euler to work with them.

Comment: maybe someone could make a complete thread/answer about these data types as blender updates?

Comment: For _Vector to Boolean_, "Why can't I get a 0 = False value with a vector other than (0,0,0)?", it's like this: _Boolean_ only accepts true or false, but while 0 is interpreted as false, no other integer or float value is false. In logic (as long as something is not somehow undefined), _not true_ = _false_ and _not false_ = _true_. Since all values other than 0 are therefore not false, they are interpreted as true to avoid getting an error for values not in (0, 1). The three vector values are concatenated into one by a logical OR operation which is always true if only one value is not false.

Comment: See if this [manual section](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/geometry_nodes/attributes_reference.html#attribute-data-types) helps. if it doesn't sort you out, perhaps you could rephrase this question, linking back to the manual, explaining where it is lacking, for you.