# "Separate XYZ" separate the Z axis in half! why?

Tags: geometry-nodes

As you can see I have not used the "Compare node" to choose the positions greater than zero but the "separate XYZ" node has already done that why is this happening?
I was following a tutorial where he was using the Compare node to have the same result as mine.
why did he do that?
[image]

Comment: There's a socket mismatch: you connect a scalar AKA float AKA value to a boolean, therefore an implicit conversion happens. You can read about those [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/267158/60486)

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Thank you 

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Would you please help me to understand this -> what is the meaning of -0.000 in the spreadsheet? what's its difference with 0.000?

Comment: There's no difference except some information on where that value comes from: multiply $1$ by $0$ and you get $0$. Multiply $-1$ by $0$ and you get $-0$. Mathematically this is the same number, also if you use a node like e.g. Math: Sign, it will return $0$ for either of the two zeros (and it will return $-1$ for negative numbers, and $+1$ for positive numbers). Comparing $-0$ and $+0$ yields *True*. This behavior is correct based on IEEE-754 standard that C++ uses, and Blender is programmed in C++.

Comment: The only way to differentiate $-0$ from $+0$ that I know of is to convert it to a string and check the length of the string.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Thank you 