# Is this normal map upside down, or is my setup wrong?

Tags: texturing, materials, normals

[image: [Here is how it looks](http://i.imgur.com/uyDEERr.jpg)]

I created this normal map with njob from the diffuse texture. I can't figure out if it confused the direction, or I messed something up with the nodes.

Comment: In the node with image of normal map change *Color* to *Non-Color Data*. It should help greatly increase the amount of effect. See [this question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4866/what-exactly-does-the-non-color-data-option-for-image-environment-textures-do) for more info

Comment: @MrZak Tried that, it gets much brighter, but it still looks like the crevices are higher

Comment: What happens if you increase the strength of normal map? Probably it could happen that normal map is baked so it emualtes extruding on another side, so on this side you see only emulated intruding.

Comment: @MrZak Yeah, maybe it was just too weak, honestly I'm not really sure which way it is anymore... :D thanks though