# Normal maps only lights up one side, while the other one stays dark with an all directional light source

Tags: texturing, shaders

I've already made a post today asking for a bit of help, but it was bad, and I did not provide enough information.

My problem is that when I use normal maps, despite the fact that I use an all-directional light, it only shines on one side.

And since I can't post more than two images, here's a gif:

[image: gif of unplugging the normal map node.]

Node setup:
[image: Node Setup]

If there's anything I can to, that would be of great help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use Non-Color Data for the texture node containing the normal map. Research the difference between color and non color data for more information. (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87000/color-vs-non-color-data)

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but that still hasn't resolved the issue at hand.

Comment: Could you upload a screenshot of the node setup please? It's hard to read in the gif.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/d14Wc
Image taken before I switched the color data, but the rest is the same..

Comment: Try changing Object space to tangent space in the normal map node.

Comment: So I initially had it set up like that, and for some reason I had this problem:
https://imgur.com/XdrgXBY
It got fixed after tweaking that setting to tangent.
Now that issue is gone for some reason?
Well, I'm not going to question it, it works.

Thank you very much for helping me though!

Comment: Shading issues can have so many reasons, but you can upload the blend file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com and link it in your question. Somebody might find the problem. (I wrote the last comment as answer, so you can accept it)

Comment: You should have *edited* your prevouis question instead of asking the same one again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing Object space to tangent space in the normal map node.

Object Space Normals are likely to cause unexpected shading effects, as they do not support object transformation and mesh deformations, like tangent space normals do.
Most of the time normal maps need to be applied relative to the surface of the mesh, not to the whole object.
(https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya-lt/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/MayaLT/files/Asts-Object-space-world-space-and-tangent-space-htm.html)

Comment: Please add an explanation as to *why* this is the answer.

Comment: Currently researching, as I am not sure why.