# Normals Remove Shade Smooth

Tags: normals, smooth

Every time I put my Normals on it remove shade smooth. I tried it on an other model and it works fine but not on this. I watched a video to fix that but it was on blender 2.8 and it was only a sphere.

How can I fix that?[image]

[image]

Comment: hello, please give more details or even share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: This topic lack clarity and most probably is a [shadow terminator issue](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/197205/53447) or you are not setting your [non-color maps color management to non-color](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/87265/53447). If itś neither of those issues, please elaborate, post screenshots, and eventually share your .blend file.

Comment: Or maybe the normals are in world/object space and were baked from flat shading.

Comment: How come this has 3 upvotes ?! ><

Answer (score 0):

With the edits you made, it looks like when the normal map's color management isn't set to `non-color`.

To fix this, got to `Shader Editor`, look at your normal maps' `Image Texture` node, and set its `Color management` to `non-color`. Do this for every different material that has a normal map.

As a rule of thumb, any texture file you use for anything else that pure color should most likely be set to  `non-color` color management. Issues may not be as obvious as with normal maps, but they are here.
More about this:

[Color vs. Non-Color data](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87000/color-vs-non-color-data/87265#87265)